# Is python is a good choice as language used to implementing my first 3D model?

Tags: python, 3d

I am C/C  /Java programmer, but lately I have started learn Python.

Moreover I have 3D Graphics on my studies. I have to create 3D model of my apartment, with dynamic camera. I am wondering if this is a good idea to merge this two issues, by writing this 3D model in python.

However as I said, I am a python beginner, so I don't know possibilities, which python can give me in this area. Which libraries/engine will be the best for a start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also checkout [Pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/), which is a higher-level library for using with OpenGL.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO C++ is a better option for 3D graphics, and you have experience in it.
Though you can have a look at PyOpenGL, python bindings for OpenGl.

> http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

If you're solely trying to learn how to do a 3d model go for the language you're the most familiar with. I'd recommend C++ or C# in that case (whichever of the 2 you meant with the second C).

If you also want to learn more about the language Python is the better choice.

But pure language wise I wouldn't say that C++/c#/python beats the other.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of options and libraries regardless of the language you choose.  But if you need a quick and dirty model you might want to check out VPython, which is python plus a simple 3D library (http://vpython.org/index.html.  There are video tutorials at: http://www.youtube.com/vpythonvideos

The programming part would likely be very easy using VPython.

The hard part is creating the object for your apartment, which you might have to do by hand, with hand coding of the coordinates to define each object.  The VPython site has a utility for importing .stl files, and many 3D programs, e.g., Blender, will export .stl files.  (I've never used this, so I can't speak to how well it works).

If you just need to model the walls, floor, and ceiling, and maybe a simple object or two, it wouldn't be hard to hand-code the coordinates.  Sketch it out on graph paper and make notes of the z axis values.